# Column re-ordering - How to store the column order?

Tags: tables, data-tables, column, rearranging

I am designing a table that enables user to re-arrange the columns according to user's preference. Below is a simple example to demonstrate.

[image]

There is a default column arrangement (A-F) but users are allowed to re-order since there are various roles using the table for different interest/ activity. And the idea is for the system to remember the new arrangement so user doesn't have to re-order the columns every time they log into the system.

Currently, I plan to add a lock or freeze table/columns button at C. So it will lock the preference and disable the re-arrange function. Is there any other ways to lock the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions. Please make sure you test them both:

1. Have a "save current layout" button and make sure it is right next to the table so that users will know it is affecting it. (law of locality)
2. Use a lock icon next to the table with a label such as "lock/unlock layout".